# Running SQL queries Async

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is it possible to run queries in async in SQL Server. For example if I need to run following query

```
SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.fn1(@Input1)
UNION
SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.fn2(@Input2)
UNION
SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.fn3(@Input3)
UNION
SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.fn4(@Input4)
```

OR without `UNION`

For Example Following queries will return 3 result set. Can I run all these in parallel.

```
SELECT [COLUMN1...COLUMNN] FROM [TABLE1...TABLEN]
SELECT [COLUMN1...COLUMNN] FROM [TABLE1...TABLEN]
SELECT [COLUMN1...COLUMNN] FROM [TABLE1...TABLEN]
```

I tried google but not able to find anything for running queries in parallel, similar like Task based programming in C#

Comment: What do you mean by `ASYNC`

Comment: I think when you have Union , sql server uses parallelism and executes the queries in parallel

Comment: You can realize async using Service Broker.

Comment: @VR46 I have updated the question. By async I mean parallel calls.

Answer (score 0):

In database there is no Asynchronous process like we have in programming. The only available option is parallelism and sql server decide about when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in standard SQL: it is synchronous. You also can't process output parameters until the stored procedure has completed.

Refer [service broker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166049.aspx) for more Information.

It is possible (see [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/)), but very likely the results will not be what you want. First and foremost going async implies breaking the transactional context assumed by the caller of the procedure (the insert occurs in a different transaction). Also, doing a reliable async (as in my linked article ) implies doing significantly more writes, so there is no performance benefit.